# A term referring to the amount of money one has?

Tags: finance, money

I am trying to find a word or term to describe the amount of money one has in posession.

**For example:**

- Account balance
- Bank statement
- outstanding balance
- Assets

In e.g the phrases "check your bank account" or "check your bank statement", if I want to imply that person X should check how much money they have available to spend, is not specific enough; as it could refer to any number of assets which are tied to a bank account.

None of these terms describe that specificity. Unless of course my not being a native speaker is glaringly obvious by the posing of this question.

Would **liquidity** be the best term for this (never mind that it has multiple similar meanings)?

Comment: Your question is  unclear. You appear to be looking for the equivalent of “cash” or “near cash “ that us money ready  available or available on demand. Assets include less liquid forms of wealth.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I don't understand how assets can be "tied to" a bank account if they are not deposited in it, except in some relatively exotic vehicles like an SdIRA. If you're talking about funds available to spend after considering pending credits and pending debits, that is the definition of *balance* — which you seem to exclude.

Answer (score 2):

The term you're looking for is a combination of two that you've already used in your question.

[**Liquid assets**](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/032715/what-items-are-considered-liquid-assets.asp):

> An asset is said to be liquid if it is easy to sell or convert into cash without any loss in its value. By definition, bank notes and checking accounts are the most liquid assets. . . .
>
> Cash is a highly liquid asset followed by the banking accounts, checkable account, short-term promissory notes, treasury bills and other government bonds.

Answer (score 1):

Check your **[funds](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/funds)**:

> money on deposit on which checks or drafts can be drawn —usually used in plural (funds)

This is more of a blanket term that encompasses all the things you listed without being too explicit.

Example usage from Merriam Webster:

> His funds were getting lower as he continued to look for a job.

Answer (score 0):

Wealth. That includes possessions, bank balances and actual cash. If that's what the question is asking.

Answer (score -1):

**lucre** [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/lucre)

> money, profit, gains, riches

It does not have to be filthy!  But if used in AmE, it is chiefly in a *humorously derogatory* sense.

As in:

> If i had his *filthy lucre* , i would spent the hell out of it too!

Better than commenting around your fiends: 'let me check my *net worth* and I shall let you know if i can attend'. *Net worth*, discussed with your intimates, accountant, divorce laywers and the IRS ... would be probably the best 'collective' term.